# Creating a sticky table header that scroll with the body overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the table header fixed to the top of the page. 
I need the tabled header to scroll horizontally with the body content.

Is there a way to either stack or combine the CSS line to achieve this?
Is there a way to keep inherited css on the element after using position:fixed?

Please check the sample code.

```css
table#live {
  max-width: 995px;
  min-width: 995px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0 25px;
}

.custom {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  " 

}

thead.fixedheader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom">
  <table id="live">

    <thead class="fixedheader">
      <tr>
        <th>hddddddddddddddddddddd1</th>
        <th>hddddddddddddddddddddd2</th>
        <th>hddddddddddddddddddddd3</th>
        <th>hddddddddddddddddddddd4</th>
        <th>hddddddddddddddddddddd5</th>
        <th>hddddddddddddddddddddd6</th>
        <th>hddddddddddddddddddddd7</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <td class="tname">
        body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body2
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
      </td>
      <td>
        body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body2
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
      </td>
      <td>
        body3
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body1
        <br>body2
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body2
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
      </td>
      <td>
        body4
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body2
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
      </td>
      <td>
        body5
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body2
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
      </td>
      <td>
        body6
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body2
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
      </td>
      <td>
        body7
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body1
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body2
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body1
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
        <br>body2
      </td>


    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of `position: sticky`? https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/ You can have a header stick in place vertically but still scroll horizontally using this technique.

Example below. The downside of this is that it's not fully supported by all browsers so if you need IE support http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky or older chrome/safari, you'd need a workaround of some kind (using JavaScript I suspect, unless some CSS ninja has a better idea!) for those browsers.

```css
table#live {
    max-width: 995px;
    min-width: 995px;
}
    
table {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0 25px;
    
}

.custom {
     width:100%;" 
}

thead.fixedheader th {
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: -moz-sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="custom">
<table id="live">

  <thead class="fixedheader">
    <tr>
      <th>hddddddddddddddddddddd1</th>
      <th>hddddddddddddddddddddd2</th>
      <th>hddddddddddddddddddddd3</th>
      <th>hddddddddddddddddddddd4</th>
      <th>hddddddddddddddddddddd5</th>
      <th>hddddddddddddddddddddd6</th>
      <th>hddddddddddddddddddddd7</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <td class="tname">
      body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body2
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
    </td>
    <td>
      body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body2
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
    </td>
    <td>
      body3
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body1
      <br>body2
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body2
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
    </td>
    <td>
      body4
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body2
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
    </td>
    <td>
      body5
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body2
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
    </td>
    <td>
      body6
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body2
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
    </td>
    <td>
      body7
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body1
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body2
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body1
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
      <br>body2
    </td>


  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</html>
```